# Failed to authenticate with Google, please try again later

Tags: macos, mail.app, calendar, gmail

macOS Big Sur 11.2.1
Cant add any account to Mail, Calendar, etc..
For example, when I try add gmail account to my Mail and follow all steps:

[image: Mail app, Google]

[image: Authentication Failed]

Same time when I log in with this account to google in browser, I see in this google account access for 3rd party untrusted applications is **enabled**:

[image: Untrusted google apps]

It is not needed, google already gives access to my MacBook Pro macOS without this setting. But I found lot "solutions" in Internet to set this security settings to On. This is not help in my case.

How to fix this bug which goes with macOS looks like couple of years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug of macOS. It was bug or troubles in some google network services like **oauth2** with urls: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/identifier...`

Solution is to use VPN with any remote GEO location.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me is connecting to a different network. I connected to my mobile data instead of my WiFi and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @penguoir (switching to 4G wifi with my phone) worked for me, but I also had to set my DNS to Google's DNS (instead of my french internet operator's DNS) and set Safari as my default browser.

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are the DNS you're looking for, maybe it had nothing to do with my issue... but now I could add my google account to Mac Os Monterey :)

Thanks a lot, it was a long time struggle !

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 2 hours trying everything (changing default browsers, rebooting, deleting stuff from KeyChain, deleting cookies from browsers, connecting to different networks and VPNs, …) until finally:

**The solution was to restart my computer into Safe Mode.**

Accounts I added in Safe Mode remained even after leaving Safe Mode, and adding new Gmail accounts started to work normally as well.